# @Transactional not working

Tags: hibernate, spring, aspectj

Trying to implement @Transactional with no sucess in a spring , hibernate project with mode AspectJ

Method on which @Transactional is used.

```
    @Transactional
    public void invokeService() throws Exception {
       Certificate certificate = (Certificate) domainObjects.get(Constants.CERTIFICATE);
       CertActObjRel accOvrRel = (CertActObjRel) domainObjects.get(Constants.CERT_ACC_OBJ_REL);
       if (certificate != null) {
        dao.insert(certificate);
        if (accOvrRel != null) {
                dao.insert(accOvrRel);
        }
        CertObjRel certObjRel = (CertObjRel) domainObjects.get(Constants.CERT_OBJ_REL);
        if (certObjRel != null) {
                List<CertObjRel> certObjRelArray = certObjRel.getCertObjRelArray();
            if (certObjRelArray != null && certObjRelArray.size() > 0) {
                    dao.insertList(certObjRelArray);
                    }

                }
        }
            insertReqCertRelation();
            insertDistributions();
            fieldIssueUOW.fieldIssueCertificate(certificate);
        }
```

The method invokeService() is an abtsract method and implemented in subclass (with Transactional annotation. No @transactional annotation used for abtsract super calss method invokeService()) and is called from Drool rules engine on base object refrence. As the class bean is not a spring bean we are using compile time weaving.

Spring config file declaration for transaction manager

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  mode="aspectj"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Spring-aspect.jar is also pasted in WEB-INF/lib folder. Testing this method with

```
 System.out.println("Transaction active:::: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
```

always returns false. If we are trying to retrieve the current session inside this method a null is returned . So it is sure that transaction is not running. Do we need to declare the class with method invokeservice() as @Aspect. Is @ Aspect a prerequisite for compiling time weaving. Even after decompiling .class file and looking at the code @Transactional remains there?.

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring documentation for 2.5

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html

> The default mode "proxy" will process annotated beans to be proxied
>   using Spring's AOP framework (following proxy semantics, as discussed
>   above, applying to method calls coming in through the proxy only). The
>   alternative mode "aspectj" will instead weave the affected classes
>   with Spring's AspectJ transaction aspect (modifying the target class
>   byte code in order to apply to any kind of method call). AspectJ
>   weaving requires spring-aspects.jar on the classpath as well as
>   load-time weaving (or compile-time weaving) enabled. (See the section
>   entitled Section 6.8.4.5, “Spring configuration” for details on how to
>   set up load-time weaving.)

Do you have load-time weaving set-up?  Do you have compile-time weaving set-up?   Have you decorated the class with an AspectJ transactional annotation rather than Spring's?

Remove the mode="aspectj" and see if it starts working for you.  If yes, then investigate whether you have the appropriate weavers at runtime.